# Using multiple checkboxes for the single variable?

Tags: php

What I am trying to achieve here is giving the user the ability to select one or all of the categories that a page will display on. The user would check any combination of 3 checkboxes and a variable will be computed and saved to the database. The values are then retrieved from the database and the checkboxes are echo'd checked accordingly.
What's happening is when more then 1 checkbox is checked only the latter value is saved e.g. if A and B are checked, only B is saved, or when A, B and C are checked, only C is saved. If just 1 checkbox is saved it's fine.

The PHP

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if ($_POST['catA'] == "a" && $_POST['catB'] == "b" && $_POST['catC'] == "c"){
            $pageCat = "abc";
        }

        if ($_POST['catA'] == "a" && $_POST['catB'] == "b"){
            $pageCat = "ab";
        }

        if ($_POST['catA'] == "a" && $_POST['catC'] == "c"){
            $pageCat = "ac";
        }

        if ($_POST['catB'] == "b" && $_POST['catC'] == "c"){
            $pageCat = "bc";
        }
            if ($_POST['catA'] == "a"){
        $pageCat = "a";
        }

        if ($_POST['catB'] == "b"){
            $pageCat = "b";
        }

        if ($_POST['catC'] == "c"){
            $pageCat = "c";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Share your HTML code too. You can use array for taking checkbox value

Comment: try all equals as "==="

Comment: You can totally reduce this code ;)

Comment: instead of individual `if` you should use `if .. else`.

Comment: better solution is just do  `$pageCat = $_POST['catA'].$_POST['catB'].$_POST['catC']`

Comment: @DharmeshPatel he is not having the issue in the php but he might have named all checkboxes same and in case of multiple select checkbox the last one was in the post

Comment: @Veerendra There is issue evident in php just go through the code above step by step and you will notice that the if conditions in the bottom override what is set above

Comment: @Dharmesh Patel thanks for your suggestion, this works and is much more simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple (not perfect) solution:

```
$pageCat = (isset($_POST['catA']) ? $_POST['catA'] : '')
    . (isset($_POST['catB']) ? $_POST['catB'] : '')
    . (isset($_POST['catC']) ? $_POST['catC'] : '');
```

Comment: @Veerendra If the checkboxes had the same names then I wouldn't of been able to set them individually and have the values saved. As previously stated, each if statement was overriding the one above if it was true.

Answer (score 0):

To have multiple entries of same variable, make it's name array:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="ACat" name="Category[A]"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="BCat" name="Category[B]"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="CCat" name="Category[C]"/>
```

Your POST will be like this:

```
array(
    "Category" => array(
        "A" => "ACat"
        "B" => "BCat"
        "C" => "CCat"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For example in such case you can use and array to get multiple values

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Car">I have a car 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

So if in the above case user selected both the values then you will get the below in the post

```
 <?php 
     echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST['vehicle']);
    ?>
```

it will give you output

Array(
    [0] => Bike,
    [1] => Car
)

And then you can process it the way you want

Answer (score 0):

to overcome this you could just use if/elseif's or you could do something posted below because if a & b are checked it goes down the list of ifs and replaces with one that is true.

With A && B

```
if ($_POST['catA'] == "a" && $_POST['catB'] == "b" && $_POST['catC'] == "c") FALSE
if ($_POST['catA'] == "a" && $_POST['catB'] == "b") TRUE $pageCat = 'ab'
if ($_POST['catA'] == "a" && $_POST['catC'] == "c") FALSE $pageCat = 'ab'
if ($_POST['catB'] == "b" && $_POST['catC'] == "c") FALSE $pageCat = 'ab'
if ($_POST['catA'] == "a") TRUE $pageCat = 'a'
if ($_POST['catB'] == "b") TRUE $pageCat = 'b'
if ($_POST['catC'] == "c") FALSE $pageCat = 'b'
Final value of pageCat = 'b'
```

try:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $pageCat = '';
    if($_POST['catA'] === "a"){
        $pageCat .= "a";
    }
    if($_POST['catB'] === "b"){
        $pageCat .= "b";
    }
    if($_POST['catC'] === "c"){
        $pageCat .= "c";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I cant see the form-part of your code.
Just to notice: Remember setting up different names for your checkboxes!

Here's a short example how to do it:

```
// 4 Checkboxes with diffrent names //
echo '<form name="form1" method="post" action="test_scroll.php">
        A<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="a">
        B<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="b">
        C<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="c">
        D<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" value="d">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/><br><br><br>';

// Loop throught the post-params and append the values of the checkboxes //
    array_pop($_POST);
    foreach($_POST as $entry){
        $values .= $entry;
    }
// here comes the result //
    echo $values;
```

The array_pop just deletes the last entry of the array which is "submit". So the values of the checkboxes are left.

If checkbox A and B are submitted the result will just be "ab". This example only works for a pure checkbox-form. If there are more values you have to pop them out before using this looping-method.

Greetings.